# Intune SDK - Conditial Access - Device not registered

Tags: android, intune

I implemented **Intune SDK** into our Flutter mobile app and are currently testing on Android. On the Azure portal, I have set up conditional access to require the device to be marked as compliant .In our app, I implemented MSAL to authenticate the user. After signing in, I call `RegisterAndEnrollAccount` - If the user does not have Company portal (broker app) installed, the app prompts them to install. Otherwise, the sign in is successful. However, when I go to connect OneDrive I get an error "*You can't get there from here*" and in the details I see that the device is not registered.

[In the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/protect/app-based-conditional-access-intune#how-app-based-conditional-access-works) it says:

> "The broker app starts the Azure AD registration process, which
> creates a device record in Azure AD"

So, I assume that when user signs in with Company P. installed the portal should automatically register the device with Azure AD - this however never happens for me.

The only error message I found in logs was:

> *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.) java.lang.RuntimeException:
> android.os.RemoteException: Unable to get WPJ device id
> at android.os.Parcel.writeException(Parcel.java:1829)
> at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:690) Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Unable to get WPJ device id
> at com.microsoft.windowsintune.companyportal.workplace.WorkplaceJoinManagerService$notify.getDeviceId(:90)
> at o.SafetyNetApi$CertificateInfo$1.onTransact(:67)
> at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:675)

However, I was not able to find any solutions online. Does anyone have an idea or tip what might be causing this?